# Android app update and keeping icon hidden

Tags: java, android, apk, updates

This is for android app development.

I have a question regarding for example if you install an app for the first time and set some settings such as hiding the app icon. Now later if there is an updated version of that app available and you update it, will the icon remain hidden or will it need to be hidden again like the first time round? so if I were to keep the settings saved in shared preferences how do you check for that shared preference on installing/ updating app so you do not need to hide the app icon each time?? or is this done automatically by android?

All help much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You could set a new value of sharedpreferences and reset the previous one..

Comment: But will doing this keep the icon hidden without the user having to re-hide it again?? Key bit here is keeping the ap icon hidden without user interaction on an app update.